# QQuick3DGeometry color not showing in point

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to add color to every point which i'm rendering in qml page. But its not working. Below is the main code which is creating the points and applying color on them. Here m_image is already set.

```
int NUM_POINTS = m_image.height() * m_image.width();;

m_bytes.resize(NUM_POINTS * stride);
float *p = reinterpret_cast<float *>(m_bytes.data());

for(int i=0;i<m_image.width();i++) {
    for(int j=0;j< m_image.height();j++) {
        *p++ = float(i)/100;
        *p++ = float(j)/100;
        QRgb rgb = m_image.pixel(i,j);
        const int gray = qGray(rgb);
        *p++ = float(gray)/100;

        QColor color = QColor::fromRgb(rgb);
        *p++ = color.red();
        *p++ = color.green();
        *p++ = color.blue();
        *p++ = 1.0f;
    }
}

setVertexData(m_bytes);
setStride(stride);
setBounds(QVector3D(-5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f), QVector3D(+5.0f, +5.0f, 0.0f));

setPrimitiveType(QQuick3DGeometry::PrimitiveType::Points);

addAttribute(QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::PositionSemantic,
             0,
             QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::F32Type);
addAttribute(QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::ColorSemantic,
             0,
             QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::F32Type);
update();
```

Here the points position are ok but the color is not correct.

Searched internet for solution

Comment: So you figured out what went wrong in your previous SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533857/qquick3dgeometry-not-displaying-geometry)? If so please close it.

Comment: You need to set the `offset` parameter of `addAttribute()` to something else then `0` in the second call. Probably `3`, but this depends on your VBO layout.

Comment: Also `red()`, `green()` and `blue()` return an `int` so you would need to use `I32Type` instead of `F32Type`. But I think what you actually want is to use `redF()`, `greenF()` and `blueF()`.

Comment: Your pseudo code is incomplete. Show the definition of `stride`.

Comment: 7*sizeof(float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your example code with this [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg) and all the points were painted black. I used `DefaultMaterial.NoLighting` in the `DefaultMaterial` assigned to the model containing the geometry which worked for me.
The only issue is the flipped image, but you will figure out how to properly position the camera in your project.

```
View3D {
    anchors.fill: parent
    camera: PerspectiveCamera {
        position: Qt.vector3d(60, 60, 210)
    }

    Model {
        scale: Qt.vector3d(100, 100, 100)
        geometry: ExampleTriangleGeometry {}
        materials: [
            DefaultMaterial {
                lighting: DefaultMaterial.NoLighting
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

```
void ExampleGeometry::updateData()
{
    clear();

    // PositionSemantic: The attribute is a position. 3 components: x, y, and z
    // ColorSemantic: The attribute is a vertex color vector. 4 components: r, g, b, and a
    int stride = 7 * sizeof(float);

    QByteArray vertexData(m_image.width() * m_image.height() * stride,
                          Qt::Initialization::Uninitialized);
    float *p = reinterpret_cast<float *>(vertexData.data());

    for (unsigned y = 0; y != m_image.height(); ++y) {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x != m_image.width(); ++x) {
            *p++ = x * 0.005f; // x
            *p++ = y * 0.005f; // y
            *p++ = 0.0f;       // z

            QColor c = m_image.pixelColor(x, y);

            *p++ = c.redF();
            *p++ = c.greenF();
            *p++ = c.blueF();
            *p++ = c.alphaF();
        }
    }

    setVertexData(vertexData);
    setStride(stride);

    setPrimitiveType(QQuick3DGeometry::PrimitiveType::Points);

    addAttribute(QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::PositionSemantic,
                 0,
                 QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::F32Type);

    addAttribute(QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::ColorSemantic,
                 3 * sizeof(float),
                 QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::F32Type);
}
```

[image]